# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure during aws cicd pipeline build

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a spring boot application + MySQL.

Everything works perfectly locally.

Even it works when I manually deploy my app jar file to Elastic Beanstalk in AWS.

But it is failing during cicd codebuild with below error. PLEASE HELP!!
Please let me know if I should provide any other details here.

**com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. 1508 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27] 1509 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27] 1510 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27] 1511 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27] 1512 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27] 1513 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27] 1514 at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na] 1515 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na] 1516 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na] 1517 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na] 1518 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na] 1519 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na] 1520 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]

.........................more..

Comment: Your build fails because probably one of your tests tries to connect to the MySQL database. You would want to mock out the repository layer in your tests.

Comment: Hi @ErvinSzilagyi. thanks for your response.
I see it was a security group issue. In Elastic Beanstalk Security Group, I had to add inbound rules in "default VPC security group" to take all traffic from "SecurityGroup for ElasticBeanstalk environment. group"

Answer (score 0):

I now see it was a security group issue. In the Elastic Beanstalk Security Group, I had to add inbound rules in "default VPC security group" to take all traffic from "SecurityGroup for ElasticBeanstalk environment. group"